# Bottleモジュールの各関数の使い方について

Tags: python, bottle

Pythonについて。

只今、『入門 Python3』を読みながら、
JupyterLabを使ってPythonを学んでいます。
OSはwindows10です。

この業界は初心者です。
言葉や言葉の使い方が正確ではないことがあります。
質問文で気になったことがあれば、何なりとご指摘くださいませ。
私はそれを揚げ足取りとは感じません。
自身の成長のために必要なことだと思っています。

---

では、質問です。
Bottleモジュールを使ったウェブサーバの実行について。
まずは、以下のコードをご覧ください。
『入門 Python3』に書かれていたコードです。

```
from bottle import route, run, static_file

@route('/')
def home() :
    return static_file('index.html', root='.')

@route('/echo/<thing>')
def echo(thing) :
    return "Say hello to my little friend : %s!" % thing


run(host='localhost', port=9999)
```

そして、このプログラムを実行し、 `http://localhost:9999/echo/Mothra` にアクセスすると、

```
Say hello to my little friend : Mothra
```

と表示されます。

私はこれを実行するのにとても時間を費やしましたが、ようやく様々な回答者のおかげで解決できました。

---

次に、私はこのコードを自分で書けるようになりたいと思い、理解するためにコードを眺めていましたが、3つ、気になったことがあります。

1つ、 `@route('/')` の、『`/`』というのはホームページという意味になるらしいのですが、
このホームページというのは、 `http://localhost:9999` のことでしょうか？

2つ、`return static_file("index.html",root=".")` より、 `static_file()` 関数は、 `index.html` というファイルを、カレントディレクトリ(同じフォルダ内)から探して返しているということでしょうか？

3つ、`Say hello to my little friend : Mothra` と表示させるのに、そもそも

```
@route('/')
def home() :
    return static_file('index.html', root='.')
```

は必要なのでしょうか？

是非、回答をお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1つ、 @route('/') の、『/』というのはホームページという意味になるらしいのですが、
>   このホームページというのは、 http://localhost:9999 のことでしょうか？

ホームページという表現が適切かはわかりませんが。。。

```
@route('/')
```

公式のマニュアルに記載が見つけられなかったので、ずれているかもですが、その理解で問題ないです。
つまりhttp://<待ち受けホストのIPアドレス>:<待ち受けアドレス>/が呼ばれたときに、その関数を呼び出すという意味です。

> 2つ、return static_file("index.html",root=".") より、 static_file() 関数は、 index.html というファイルを、カレントディレクトリ(同じフォルダ内)から探して返しているということでしょうか？

マニュアルに

> Be careful when specifying a relative root-path such as root='./static/files'. The working directory (./)
>   and the project directory are not always the same.

とあるように、開発ディレクトリの「カレント」とサーバ動作時の「カレント」は異なる場合があります。つまり、サーバ起動時に「カレント」としたディレクトリから「相対パスで」静的なファイルを特定し返却することになります。

> は必要なのでしょうか？

以下の記載にあるように静的なhtmlを表示する場合に推奨されています。（Fileオブジェクトを返却することもできるようですね。)。Mimeタイプのハンドリングと403/404のケアをしてくれるようです。

> You can directly return file objects, but static_file() is the recommended way to serve static files. It automatically guesses a mime-type, adds a Last-Modified header, restricts paths to a root directory for security
>   reasons and generates appropriate error responses (403 on permission errors, 404 on missing files).